# Alpha values of PNG

Tags: image, png

Very quick question, in an app I need to test the alpha of a pixels in an image. Is completely transparent 0 or 255?

(I'm reading the bytes of each [sub]pixel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is completely transparent 0 or 255?

0

Answer (score 3):

Alpha blending takes a proportion (between 0 and 255) of the underlying image, mixes it in with the overlay image, and the result is kept.  Because the proportion ranges from "nothing in the overlay" at 0, to "everything from the overlay, nothing from the underlying image" at 255, the answer is

Completely Transparent is an alpha value of 0.

Comment: mixes it with the overlay image?